# Scrape content from page that loads content after html loaded

Tags: screen-scraping

I am trying to get a section of a page that does not load completely until all the JS is run after the html.

https://www.openrent.co.uk/properties-to-rent/greater-london?term=Greater%20London&area=1&prices_min=400&prices_max=900&bedrooms_min=0&bedrooms_max=1

The section I am after is...

Your filtered search is displaying: 1 of 74 properties found

But the 1 in this section is loaded later after the page loads.  How could I get this value ?
The 74 is loaded with the HTML so can get this no problem.

Comment: What kind of software are you using to do the actual scraping?

Comment: ah sorry, that would help, it would be PHP

Comment: I might be pointing out the the obvious but as a matter of principle you wanna make sure  you're legally allowed to the data you're after. If Javascript were to be involved and you seem to have ascertained that, take a look at Selenium through a WebDriver (https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) or PhantomJS (albeit unmaintained, might be enough for your case: https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs)

Comment: I am only after the data for personal use to know when new listings show so I can 'try' to get in first.  Seems their email gets to me sometimes after the listing is taken.  I would be using cronjob and php to scan page every 20 minutes and have my script email me when there are changes.  Could not use page size count as it changes even when nothing is new!

Comment: Just checking these out and think it is used on a pc with a virtual server installed ?  or can this be used on a normal web server ?  I am not wanting my pc on all day and night, I was hoping to get a simple setup to grab the number see if it changed from the one I stored and if so email my that it changed so i can get on it as soon as possible.